# how to block anyone from requesting a url and with another user's cookie

Tags: security, flask, web, python-requests, request

So I made a twitter clone but I discovered that anyone can just request a URL like this:

```
import requests
requets.post("/follow-user_u={target_user}", cookie={"username": "username"})
```

and make it so anyone can follow them if they change the cookie to another user's username

So how do I protect against this ?
I'm using flask

Comment: I cookie that contains the user name is a bad ide. What prevents the user from editing that cookie and e.g. claim to be a different user? Usually session cookies are used with a very large random number as session id and then on server side maintain a table that assigned each session id a user name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any data like a cookie that you store on the end users computer can be changed/spoofed, absolutely anything. You need to use sessions... Flask has built in sessions that you can learn about here https://pythonbasics.org/flask-sessions/.